# Install npm packages programmatically

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

How to install npm packages programmatically? i have multiple local repos and each has its own package.json. Now i want to install packages from all those repos into a single node_modules folder which is outside of all repos. Can someone provide a sample script/guide for this?

```
var repos = ['repo1', 'repo2', 'repo3'];

repos.forEach(function(repoName, index) {
   //todo: install packages from this repo. 
   // dest: '/Users/lokesh/Documents/node_modules'
});
```

Comment: the package.json can handle all of that

Comment: Can you add clarification on what exactly you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score -1):

One option is to use gradle node plugin and use config nodeModulesDir specific a global nodeModulesDir.

```
node {
  // Version of node to use.
  version = '0.11.10'

  // Version of npm to use.
  npmVersion = '2.1.5'

  // Version of Yarn to use.
  yarnVersion = '0.16.1'

  // Base URL for fetching node distributions (change if you have a mirror).
  distBaseUrl = 'https://nodejs.org/dist'

  // If true, it will download node using above parameters.
  // If false, it will try to use globally installed node.
  download = true

  // Set the work directory for unpacking node
  workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/nodejs")

  // Set the work directory for NPM
  npmWorkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/npm")

  // Set the work directory for Yarn
  yarnWorkDir = file("${project.buildDir}/yarn")

  // Set the work directory where node_modules should be located
  nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}
```

I don't know if this is helpful, if you don't want use gradle.

[Gradle Node Plugin](https://github.com/srs/gradle-node-plugin/blob/master/docs/node.md)